# Getting Null From MongoDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express

Why my Code Giving me Null

```js
async function run() {
  try {
    await client.connect();

    const productsCollection = client.db("inventory").collection("items");

    // Get All Products
    app.get('/products', async (req, res) => {
      const query = {};
      const cursor = productsCollection.find(query);
      const products = await cursor.toArray();
      res.send(products);
    });

    // Get Single Product
    app.get('/products/:id', async (req, res) => {
      const id = req.params.id;
      console.log(id);
      const query = {_id: ObjectId(id)};
      const product = await productsCollection.findOne(query);
      res.send(product);
    })
  } 
  finally {
    
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);
```

I do not understand why Null is showing?
And there is no error in giving products /id
And It doesn't even showing anything
And this error is showing in the front end console
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Answer (score 0):

In mongo, you should use await on every event that is related to the database.
this is because it takes time to actually retrieve the data from the collection
and the javascript code will not wait unless you tell it to.

in your example

`const cursor = productsCollection.find(query);`

should be

`const cursor = await productsCollection.find(query);`

this is my first note

My second note is to share your frontend code and I will edit the answer if there is any thing to add

Comment: Bro Get All Products Is Ok. Problem is in Get Single Product Section. front end code it here    const { id } = useParams();

    useEffect(()=>{
        const url = `http://localhost:5000/products/${id}`;
        console.log(id);
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data));
  }, [id]);